# Find number form except for specific number with regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to find number form except specific number.
For example, I want to find these kind of numbers:

```
1.214,41
4,431.43
143,134.43
355.352,41
443,113,134.43
365.115.352,41
```

And I can do it with this regex:

```
(\d{1,3}(,|.)){1,4}
```

Except. number is `0.00` or `0,00`. I know that I can exclude these numbers with:

```
^(0.00|0,00)
```

But I o not know how to combine both regexes.

My text looks like this. I have provided minimal example, text is much much longer and requested phrases are all over the place:

```
Total 341,431.43
Saldo 0.00
Saldo 0,00
Total 1,431.43
Total 0,00
Saldo 0.60
...
```

And my full regex looks like this:

```
(Saldo|Total)\s(\d{1,3}(,|.)){1,4}
```

With:

```
re.search(regex, text)
```

I want to get:

```
Total 341,431.43
Total 1,431.43
Saldo 0.60
...
```

But sometimes I get rows with 0.00 or 0,00.

Comment: If you're using python why not just check both separately, it will be cleaner, faster, easier to read, easier to maintain, etc.

Comment: how to do that? I have a lot of different numbers in the text

Comment: Show an [MCVE] and I'd be happy to help

Comment: Please check the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
\b(?:Saldo|Total)\s(?!0[.,]00\b)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d\d\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(?:Saldo|Total)\s` Match either Saldo or Total followed by a whitespace char
- `(?!0[.,]00\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not `0.00` or `0,00` directly to the right
- `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d\d` Match 1-3 digits, optional repetitions of 3 digits and `.` and 2 digits
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qMHTaT/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/lE40BF)

```
import re

strings = [
    "Total 341,431.43",
    "Saldo 0.00",
    "Saldo 0,00",
    "Total 1,431.43",
    "Total 0,00",
    "Saldo 0.60"
]

pattern = r"\b(?:Saldo|Total)\s(?!0[.,]00\b)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d\d\b"
for s in strings:
    m = re.search(pattern, s)
    if m:
        print(s)
```

Output

```
Total 341,431.43
Total 1,431.43
Saldo 0.60
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for everything. If you're processing a bunch of independent lines, process them separately. In that case, you can apply as many tests as you need:

```
incl = re.compile(r'(Saldo|Total)\s(\d{1,3}(,|.)){1,4}')
excl = {'0.00', '0,00'}
for line in text.splitlines():
    if incl.fullmatch(line) and line not in excl:
        print(line)
```

Or you can build a list for later use:

```
result = [line for line in text.splitlines() if incl.fullmatch(line) and line not in excl]
print('\n'.join(result))
```

If you're getting your data from a file, it's better to replace `for line in text.splitlines():` with

```
for line in file:
    line.rstrip('\n')
```

Comment: I have provided minimal example, text is much much longer and requested phrases are all over the place

Comment: Your question was how to include one expression but exclude another. My answer isn't meant as a copy and paste solution, but rather a general way to solve the problem